# How to implement work-to-rule in software development

Tags: contracts, productivity, performance, efficiency

I'm looking for ways how to implement [work-to-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-to-rule) to make software developer work as inefficient as it can be but still follow the permanent job contract rules.

The question is how to do strike but do not lose your job.

Comment: What is your goal by doing this? I mean what result are you trying to get from your employer?

Comment: Try missing a few key deliverable deadlines. What's that? Software Development you say? Never mind - nobody would notice :) {Disclaimer - long time software developer}

Comment: Sounds like a typical [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Voting to close as 'unclear what you're asking'

Comment: Asking questions on Stackexchange sites is a good start.

Comment: The whole point of work-to-rule is that a large number of participants  (normally organised by a union) simultaneously go slow - because it's impractical for the employer to fire everyone and get replacements without incurring greater costs than simply acceeding to their demands. Industries which employ small numbers of high-value individuals, where reputation counts, have a very different dynamic. And doing it alone is painting a target on your head.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking for ways how to implement work-to-rule to make software
>   developer work as inefficient as it can be but still follow the
>   permanent job contract rules.

- If you are in a union, make sure you discuss this with your union rep and get union approval beforehand
- Know and fully understand the specifics of your contract
- Know and fully understand the specifics of work rules in your locale
- Make sure everyone in your workgroup sticks together and follows the same plan
- Be prepared in the event you are fired
- Be prepared to fight actions against you in a court of law
- Don't do anything at all that isn't required by your contract
- Don't ever come in early or stay late if it isn't required by contract
- Take all the breaks you are entitled to by contract, without exception

This is not something I would ever advise someone to do in my locale (the US).

Where I live you will almost certainly lose your non-union job, and you will very likely lose your professional reputation. Perhaps in your locale and your contract this won't be the case, or perhaps you don't care.

Comment: "Where I live you will almost certainly lose your job" this is exactly what work-to-rule is NOT about. The question is how to do strike but do not lose your job.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch In the US very few IT people are unionized; and without the backing a union gives would be promptly sacked and replaced for trying it.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the US, you can be fired for a slowdown as easily as for a strike. More easily, maybe, because you're making it trivial for them to demonstrate that you're incompetent. This sounds like an extremely bad idea.

Comment: You can be fired easily for a slowdown, but in many places (the OP seems to be European) getting fired this way is actually quite profitable for the employee and therefore something companies don't like to do.

Comment: Valid points, folks. I can see doing a slowdown as psrt of a union action, but without that kind of support I'm surprised that being fired for incompetence, real or deliberate, is ever good for anyone. Even where governments are union-friendly.